# Reed-Solomon Code for large code length and errors

Tags: large-files, largenumber, reed-solomon

I'm new to Error Correction Code (ECC). Take the Reed-Solomon code (RS(n,k)) as an example, it encodes k symbols into n symbols with n-k parity symbols and it can correct (n-k)/2 error symbols.

I want to know **whether there is design or implementation for RS(n,k) with large n like 600, and k be 400?** This means it can correct about 100 error symbols. If it is not possible, what is the limitation? If it's possible, **what is the time cost**, especially for decoding since it is more complicated than encoding, for big data.

I look up several pieces of literature. Although n=544 is possible, however, the current solution only supports RS(544,514) which means the error correction capability is only (544-514)/2=15.

I know the hardest part of decoding is to solve key equation. But I don't know how to estimate the time cost of decoding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that as n in RS(n,k) becomes larger, the field becomes larger. For n = 512 to 1023, a 10 bit field is needed. If the data is 400 bytes, that is actually 320 10 bit symbols.

RS(600,400) is not an issue. For RS(n,k) with number of parities = number of syndromes = n-k = p, encoding has time complexity O(pn). Generating syndromes is O(pn). Decoding is O(p^2) if using Berlekamp Massey or Sugiyama extended Euclid decoder, or O((p/2)^3) if using Peterson Gorenstein Zierler matrix inversion.

---

As example of a "larger" code, BCH code uses elements of GF(2^n), but limits the encoding polynomial to 1 bit coefficients. For example, there is a BCH(48600,48408), 48408 data bits, 192 parity bits, but syndrome generation and error decoding is done in GF(2^16). It is used for a digital broadcast known as DVBS2.